# NGROk with webpack + react on rails configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

Currently running rails 5.1 with webpacker gem
using react webpacker and ngrok for rails port 3000. problem is react is not rendering on the custom ngrok domain route.
Tried setting the `config/webpacker.yml` in set development dev_server `https: true` also did try the proxy.

Im getting the `https://0.0.0.0:8080/packs/hello_react.js net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`
Tried doing foreman start and putting

`web: bundle exec rails s
webpacker: ./bin/webpack-dev-server`

in procfile and doing foreman start. same issue. but would work if I use localhost:3000 but not the ngrok generated one.